# How to tanslate a JSP InputStream into a ServletResponse?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm in a Tomcat and have a String with JSP Content. And I try to get the HttpServletResponse means the HTML Output. In normal case you call the JSP and the WebContainer translate it to an Servlet and generates the Output.

But I have no JSP as File, just a String with the Content of an JSP. Is there a Class or Factory where I can put the Stream and get it processed?

thanks in anticipation

Comment: What is a 'String with JSP content'? And what does your title have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** there is not readily available solution for this.

**But, you can try out this:**

- Write the JSP string to a file inside the web application content root. Let's say `/tmp/jspstring.jsp`. Use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/tmp/jspstring.jsp")` to get the path of the new jsp.
- Using `RequestDispatcher` include the newly created JSP, such that the server will process the JSP using

Comment: Ok, I've hoped there is a better solution, but I think it will work for me.